# svn authorization failed

Tags: svn, sourceforge, authorization

I do:

```
svn ci filename
```

and get:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Authorization failed
```

Why don't I get a prompt for username and password?

Details: I am the administrator of the project on sourceforge. I did svn checkout without problems. Doing this didn't help, too: `svn ci -m '' --username=myusername`. Again, this username is the admin of the project. On Windows I can commit by using ssh dsa.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer was of great help. Although I had to `svn co svn+ssh://myname@repository_url`

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by doing checkout again, this time from a svn+ssh://url instead of svn://url. (I tried `svd sw --relocate` unsuccesfully)

Answer (score 1):

Needed me hours to fix it..
Open View 'SVN Repositories' under "Windows/Show View/Other"
in the View, open the Project
Right-click: 'Location Properties'
Under URL change the 'svn://' to 'svn+ssh.//', like cyporg mentioned
Finish, give login, and it should work again, without new checkout :)